# Twilio api play message before call hangup

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am hanging up a call like this(java):

```
            Call.updater('somesid').setStatus(Call.UpdateStatus.COMPLETED).update();
```

I would like to play a message(not via some audio file, but via the twilio 'say' verb) before this call is ended.

How do I do it if its possible?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Instead of just completing the call with the API request, you can redirect the call to some new TwiML instead. To do so, you need a new URL to send the call to and you update it like this:

```
Call.updater(callSid)
        .setMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
        .setUrl(URI.create(newUrl))
        .update();
```

The new URL should then return TwiML that [`<Say>`s](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) the message you want and then hangs up with [`<Hangup/>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup). Like this:

```
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">Sorry, I have to hang up now.</Say>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```